# C++ / Converting time(NULL) to exact years, months, weeks, hours, and minutes from Jan 1, 1970

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, time, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write C++ code that counts the number of years, months, weeks, hours and minutes from Jan 1, 1970. I am including the code I currently have. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <time.h>


int main(){

double seconds, minutes, days, weeks, months, years, hours;


seconds = time(NULL); 
minutes = seconds / 60;
hours = minutes / 60;
days = hours / 24;
weeks = days / 7;
months = weeks / 4;
years = days / 365;

months = (int) (days / 30.42) % 12;
weeks = (int) (days / 7) % 52;
days = (int) (hours / 24) % 24;
hours = (int) (minutes / 60) % 1;
minutes = (int) (seconds / 60) % 60; 


printf("%d years \n", (int)years); 
printf(" %d months \n", (int)months);
printf(" %d weeks\n", (int)weeks);
printf(" %d days \n", (int)days);
printf(" %d minutes\n", (int)minutes);
printf(" %d hours\n\n", (int)hours);


system("pause");
}
```

Comment: why not use `localtime`? It will convert `time_t` into `struct tm` which is exactly what you need.

Comment: No leap year logic.  Need to explain the magic constant 30.42

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Leap year logic was not required. I think the 30.42 constant is to make up for leap years. Not sure though since I am new to this. 

I am having issues with having the system figure out exactly what time(null) is as one cohesive unit of time values. 

I wish I could use local time but I have to use the functions specified above. Thank you guys keep them coming :)

Comment: You have 2 week calculations:  Are you looking for week of the month or week of the year or both?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to consider in which timezone you want this information.

Then instead of writing the code yourself, use either `gmtime_r` to get the result in UTC or `localtime_r` to get the result in your current `TZ`'s local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out standard functions `locatime()` and `gmtime()` first.  They readily meet your goal.

```
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  if (t == -1) { printf("time() failure"); return; }
  struct tm *tmp;
  tmp = localtime(&t);
  if (tmp == NULL) { printf("gmtime() failure"); return; }
  int seconds = tmp->tm_sec;
  int minutes = tmp->tm_min;
  int hours = tmp->tm_hour;
  int days = tmp->tm_mday + 1;
  int weeks = (days-1)/7; // OP code has 2 `weeks` calculated, go with week-of-the-month rather than week-of-the-year
  days -= weeks*7;
  int months = tmp->tm_mon + 1;
  int years = tmp->tm_year + 1900;

  printf("%d years \n", years);
  printf("%d months \n", months);
  printf("%d weeks \n", weeks);
  printf("%d days \n", days);
  printf("%d hours \n", hours);
  printf("%d minutes \n", minutes);
  printf("%d seconds \n", seconds);
```

---

If your truly want to do this yourself you have some work to do.  You did not specify timezone, so let's go with the easiest: UTC.  Further, let's do this in `unsigned` as much as we can as it simpler.  You can change it to `int` if needed.

```
// Get the time
time_t t = time(NULL);
if (t < 0) {
  ; // handle this error condition
}
unsigned seconds = t%60;
t /= 60;
unsigned minutes = t%60;
t /= 60;
unsigned hours = t%24;
t /= 24;
// now begins the tricky bit.
// `t` represent the number of days since Jan 1, 1970.

// I would show more here, but unless I know you are wanting this path, I'd rather not do the work.


printf("%d years \n", (int)years);
printf("%d months \n", (int)months);
printf("%d weeks\n", (int)weeks);
printf("%d days \n", (int)days);
printf("%d minutes\n", (int)minutes);
printf("%d hours\n\n", (int)hours);
```

Comment: Chux... Thanks! this is more of what I am looking for. It is very tricky. I am attaching my latest version of code. I know some of the mods are off as any % 1 is 0 but I am still working it out. Any insight folks? Thanks for all of the replies!!

Comment: I edited my post above to reflect what I have so far. I think its somewhat close...

Comment: You are still quite far off.  In your local code, try temporarily replacing `seconds = time(NULL);` with `seconds = 4*24*3600 + 3*3600 + 2*60 +1` and get your code to report Days:4,Hours:3, Minutes:2, Seconds:1.  Forget the YMW fields for now.  Once you get that working, re-edit your post.  GTG

Comment: For future reference, the beset place to start is with the command you already know; [look that up](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) and check out the "see also" section and (in this case) the "referenced by" sections.